# Custom query in custom repo cannot be found

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I just want to get the last record so I cannot call my custom query in custom build repo. Error is below. Do you know what it could be?

Note: Normal find(), findBy() like queries work fine. If there is a easier way of doing it then please tell me how to do it.

Thanks

**ERROR:**

```
 Undefined method 'getLastRecord'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

**MAIN CLASS:**

```
namespace Booking\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="CashQuery")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Booking\AdminBundle\Entity\CashQueryRepository")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CashQuery
{
}
```

**REPO:**

```
namespace Booking\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CashQueryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getLastRecord()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT d FROM AdminBundle:CashQuery d ORDER BY d.id DESC LIMIT 1'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

**TRYING TO USE WITH THIS:**

```
$dcq = $em->getRepository('BookingAdminBundle:CashQuery')->getLastRecord();
if (! $dcq) {
    echo 'CashQuery could not found';
    return false;
}
echo $dcq->getCreatedAt();
```

Comment: I think all the queries from a custom entity repository should begin with findBy or findOneBy. Did you try changing the name and including findBy or findOneBy at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're overwriting the `Entity` annotation. Try removing the second one:

```
namespace Booking\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="CashQuery")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Booking\AdminBundle\Entity\CashQueryRepository")
 */
class CashQuery
{
}
```

Comment: Ooops. That's the one!